# add filter to change specific part of function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filtering

I am trying to remove a class from a button in woocommerce that is in the wc_cart_functions.php file. There is a string in the `wc_add_to_cart_message` function which inserts this string:

`<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s`

```
function wc_add_to_cart_message( $products, $show_qty = false ) {
$titles = array();
$count  = 0;

if ( ! is_array( $products ) ) {
    $products = array( $products );
    $show_qty = false;
}

if ( ! $show_qty ) {
    $products = array_fill_keys( array_keys( $products ), 1 );
}

foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
    $titles[] = ( $qty > 1 ? absint( $qty ) . ' &times; ' : '' ) . sprintf( _x( '&ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'Item name in quotes', 'woocommerce' ), strip_tags( get_the_title( $product_id ) ) );
    $count += $qty;
}

$titles     = array_filter( $titles );
$added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', $count, 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

// Output success messages
if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
    $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
} else {
    $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
}

wc_add_notice( apply_filters( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', $message, $product_id ) );
}
```

I tried to create a filter which would just replace that specific string, since it appears twice and in both instances I want the class removed. This does not seem to work though:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'add_to_cart_mod');
 function add_to_cart_mod($message) {
    $message = str_replace ( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s' , '<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', $message );
 return $message;
}
```

With this filter set as it is, I still see the button with the same unchanged class. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter expects to find `%s`, but that was replaced by the previous call to `sprintf`: these  `%s` are not there any more.

You could try with a regular expression:

```
$message = preg_replace ('/(<a [^>]+ )class="button wc-forward"/', 
                         '$1class="button"', $message );
```

The `[^>]+` part means: any sequence of characters that does not contain a `>` (end of `a` tag).

`$1` means: whatever was matched between the parentheses. It could be something like `<a href="http://example.com"`.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. That completely removes the class property altogether. Couple questions about your answer; what is (<a [^>]+ ) doing and also what is $1 referring to?

Comment: I fixed that: now the class is replaced. I added explanations as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'add_to_cart_mod');

function add_to_cart_mod( $message ) {  
    // Output success messages
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }

    return $message;
}
```

Comment: Hey Andy, that removes the $added_text portion of the code, resulting in just the button and no text following. But the button class works